# SwfPlayer in WPF application : Shockwave not found

Tags: c#, wpf, flash

First of all, I work in C# / XAML on Visual Studio C# 2013 Express.
I write today for a swf player in a wpf application. I read many discuss on this subjetcs but no one can solve my problem. I use a PageSwitcher, each page inherit from UserControl class and I create a button for each .swf file in a directory. This work fine. When I click on one of them, I want to open a new page wich is the swf viewer. I can open a new page, but my pdf viewer not work. I tried many ways to resolve my problem, but nothing work. I have a WinForm application wich do what I want, but I can't add it in my WPF application I try a WindowsFormHost but I still have the same error : Type or namespace 'AxShockwaveFlashObjects' not found, whereas I add AxInterop.ShockwaveFlashObjects.dll and/or Interop.ShockwaveFlashObjects.dll

Here is my code :
XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="WPFPageSwitch.swf"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid x:Name="Container">

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

C#

```
namespace WPFPageSwitch
{
    public partial class swf : System.Windows.Controls.UserControl, ISwitchable
    {
        public swf(string swf)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost swfPlayer = new System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost();

            AxShockwaveFlashObjects.AxShockwaveFlash axShockwaveFlash = new AxShockwaveFlashObjects.AxShockwaveFlash();

            swfPlayer.Child = axShockwaveFlash;

            Container.Children.Add(swfPlayer);
        }

    }
}
```

Somebody can help me ?
The error is here : AxShockwaveFlashObjects.AxShockwaveFlash axShockwaveFlash = new AxShockwaveFlashObjects.AxShockwaveFlash();

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference to it.
AxShockwaveFlashObjects is a COM library to allow you to integrate Flash content into your .NET application. Demo [Here](http://deepak-sharma.net/2013/03/15/how-to-play-flash-in-windows-forms-application-using-c-shar/)